# Rewriting URL's to same directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm completely rewriting the code of my website because a lot can be optimized. Also the rewrite rules I'm currently using aren't that optimized I think.

I want URL's like below:

```
Cities:
domain.com/new-york
domain.com/chicago
domain.com/dallas
...

Categories:
domain.com/fruit
domain.com/meat
domain.com/beverage
...
```

At the moment, I have this code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+) index.php?task=cityorcategory&cityorcat=$1 [L]
```

What I do in the index file is as followed:

1. Check if the task is "cityorcategory"
2. Put the value of "cityorcat" in a variable
3. Compare the variable to the Category database table
4. If it's a category, I redirect to the category template
5. Otherwise, I redirect to the city template

I don't want to check if the variable is a category in the index file because I think this isn't good for the website performance.

I'm not sure what I need to change here. Can I keep the URL structure like index.php?task=cityorcategory&cityorcat=$1 or is that a bad idea?

What do I need to change so that I can rule out the variable comparision in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite to a separate page in case of a cityorcategory, say, /city.php.

Or you could just consider the index.php as a distribution centre, and build a switch on $_GET['task']

```
switch ($_GET['task']) {

  case 'cityorcategory':
  // redirect
  break;

  case 'countrycategory':
  // redirect
  break;

  default:
    echo "Not a category, so process";
  break;
 }
```

If you are just asking: How do I know whether a catagory is in the database.. Just run a query. I assume you will have to build the page based on the category anyway. If you run the query and you get 0 records returned, the category does not exist, and you can show the defaul index page.

Alternatively, if you do not have a lot of categories, and they do not change, you could create an array of categories, and check against the array with existing categories. That is however, a little odd way. but if you are dead-set agains categories..

In the last case: You could do a HTACCESS match against the existing categories, again: If these are of a limited number & do not change.

Comment: So it's absolutely necessary to do a query or compare to an array? It's for example not possible to have something like index.php?task=city&cityname=$1 and index.php?task=category&catname=$1? I guess htaccess can't detect which of the 2 is the correct one because they have the same URL structure? PS: I have a few hundred categories and they change almost weekly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rewritemaps http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html and have a cronjob build the map every x minutes. Depends on how often the data is changed.